# session and state Management in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

May i know how can i use session and state management in MVC4.
Im using Webapi to fetch .
Im creating a shopping cart app ,so in classic asp.net webforms we store user specific data
using session management.

Please let me know how can we achieve the same in MVC with simple example.
It would be helpful if the example includes caching related stuff as well.

Comment: You can use `Session` as used in asp.net webforms. We dont have `ViewState` instead passing data between controller and views are done using `ViewData`